# Summing from m to n with initial modifier from 0 to 1

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

I am trying to find costs in a system, in the system going from Level 0 to Level 1 has a constant cost of $C$. As a result the cost to go from Level 1 to Level 2 is $C + i$ where $i$ is our cost increment for each increased Level. E.g. For $C = 10$ and $i = 5$ going from Level 0 to Level 1 would have a cost of $10$; similarly going from Level 1 to Level 2 would have a cost of $10 + 5 = 15$. How would I go about finding the costs for transitioning between two arbitrary Levels $m$ and $n$.

I know that if I have $C = 0$, my cost simply can be found out by using the formula $c =i\sum_{k=m}^n{k}$ where $c$ is the cost of transitioning from Level $m$ to Level $n$.

How would I incorporate $C$ into this formula?

Answer (score 1):

Following on from [William Elliot](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/426203/william-elliot)'s answer, if we let some $c(k)$ be the cost to go from Level $k$ to $k + 1$, we can express $c(k) = C + ki$, where $i$ is some constant increase factor. Let us express the cost to go from some Level $m$ to some Level $n$ as $c(m,n) = \sum_{k=m}^{n-1}{c(k)}$. Therefore to calculate the transition cost from Level $m$ to Level $n$, we can use summation laws to break $c(m,n)$ down into a simple $O(1)$ function:

\begin{align}
c(m,n) = \sum_{k=m}^{n-1}{c(k)} & = \sum_{k=m}^{n-1}{C + ki} \\
& = \sum_{k=m}^{n-1}{C} + i\sum_{k=m}^{n-1}{k} \\
& = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}{C} - \sum_{k=1}^{m-1}{C} + i\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}{k} - \sum_{k=1}^{m-1}{k}\right) \\
& = \dots \\
& = C(n - m) + \frac{1}{2}i(n^2 - m^2 + m - n)
\end{align}